# Конфликт тем DarkActionBar и Theme.Light

Tags: android, android-themes

Здоровья всем! 
Я даже не знаю с чего начать. Есть у меня приложение в котором есть navigation drawer, сейчас я пытаюсь добавить ActionBar tabs с возможностью свайпить. 
Конечно же после добавления последних приложение вылетело. После долгих экспрементов выяснилось что с темой Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar начинает работать navigation drawer, а с темой Theme.Light - ActionBar tabs.

Надеюсь хоть как-то смог объяснить в чем проблема. Какие могут быть идеи?

вылетаетс такой ошибкой:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.se...

на этой строке (вообще где используется **actionBar**):
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

**Класс Main**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import net.seosprint.www.seosprint.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;


public class ManagereklActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

**И вспомогательный класс:**

```
import net.seosprint.www.seosprint.GamesFragment;
import net.seosprint.www.seosprint.MoviesFragment;
import net.seosprint.www.seosprint.TopRatedFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: Пока что не очень понятно. Покажите логи ошибки, покажите строку возникновения оной. Покажите как у вас табы реализованы. Их можно 3-5 совершенно разными способами сделать. В общем сейчас слишком мало информации для получения ответа

Comment: Возможно потмоу что одна тема из саппорт библиотеки, а другая нет? И из-за этого какой-то конфликт

Comment: Вот обновил информацию